# Reac-bootstrap: Warning: Specifying a `<Nav>` `activeKey` or `activeHref` in the context of a `<TabContainer>` is not supported

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

The component actually works as it should, but everytime a tab is changed, this warning is thrown:

```
Warning: Specifying a `<Nav>` `activeKey` or `activeHref` in the 
context of a `<TabContainer>` is not supported. Instead use 
`<TabContainer activeKey={First} />`.
```

Not really sure how to suppress it!

I'm controlling the `activeKey` with a MobX store. Here's a sample:

```
<Tab.Container defaultActiveKey={"first"} activeKey={store.key} onSelect={store.handleSelect} >
    <NavigationBar store = {this.store}/>
    <Tab.Content animation={false} >
        <Tab.Pane  eventKey={"first"} >
            <FirstTab store = {this.store}  eventKey={"first"} />
        </Tab.Pane>
        <Tab.Pane   unmountOnExit={true} eventKey={"second"}>
            <SecondTab store = {this.store} />
        </Tab.Pane>
        <Tab.Pane  unmountOnExit={true} eventKey={"third"}>
            <ThirdTab store = {this.store} />
        </Tab.Pane>
    </Tab.Content>
</Tab.Container>
```

and in my MobX store:

```
@observable key = "First";
@action handleSelect = (key) => {
    this.key = key;
    if(key === undefined){
        this.key = "First"
    }
};
```

And the `NavigationBar` component:

```
<Nav bsStyle="tabs" activeKey={this.props.store.key} >
    <NavItem eventKey={"First"}>
        // Some icon
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={"Second"}>
        // Some icon
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={"Third"}>
        // Some icon
    </NavItem>
</Nav>
```

As said, everything works as intended. I just get this warning thrown in my face everytime the state of the tabs change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is correct. The problem is when used inside a TabContainer, the Tab container handles the active nav item itself in order to manage which tab is selected. If you specify it on the Nav, you now have two places that are trying to set the active key of the nav, which isn't great so RB ignores the one you set in the Nav explicitly and warns you it's ignoring it.

Comment: I have to specify it on the `Nav` because otherwise, the chosen tab will not be highlighted on the click event. That's the only reason I have it there, in fact :-/

Comment: that's not correct, the TabContainer will pass the activeKey (if you configured it correctly) to the nav and it will be highlighted, just like in the documentation examples

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to move the `<NavigationBar />` component outside the `<Tab.Container />` component, and add the `onSelect` function to that as well(to handle the active tab). No more warning then.

Comment: thats a solution to disabling the warning, but the warning was validly telling you something was wrong. Now its still wrong but you aren't hearing about it.

Comment: Alright, can you share how you would solve it from the sample code then?

Comment: just don't pass `activeKey` in Navigation when in a tab container.

Comment: Not possible. Then the Navigationbar will not be able to tell which is the active tab(and thus mark it lighter than the others)

Comment: In the context of a TabContainer It WILL be able too know the active tab because you supplied activeKey to TabContainer and TabContainer is injecting it's activeKey into the Navbar for you. The warning is telling you that, and letting you know that its _ignoring_ the prop you set to do that.